# How to run multiple the same spider in Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have a url list, for example [' http://example.com/page1 ', http://example.com/page2',...].

These urls are in a domain name, and I've written a crawler with Scrapy, and I need to run those urls together, using the same crawler. If I have 10 urls, I want to create 10 of the same process to run the crawler to improve efficiency. Is there a solution?

I tried to use CrawlerProcess to run the crawler, but if the urls were too many, it would remind me of an error with too many TCP connections. Although the crawler is always running, this method is not conducive to maintenance.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
page_urls = ['http://example.com/page1', 'http://example.com/page2',]

for page_url in page_urls:
    process.crawl('vimeo', start_urls=[page_url])
process.start()
```

Comment: what is the output of this code ?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to improve the number of concurrent requests by a single spider, and not specifically to spawn multiple spiders in parallel, I suggest that you simply play around with the settings like [`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY), [`CONCURRENT_REQUEST`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) or [`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-domain).